# How to detect disconnection of flash client from php server?

Tags: php, flash

How can the disconnection or Closure of the flash client be detected while using a php backend which ensures that only active client usernames are present in the datbase. My approaches were to use some polling method - where the client sends some message to the server periodically else the server deletes the client's name from the DB assuming it is closed - or to use some augmenting javascript code that informs the backend of a closure event. This won't help in case of an abrupt, improper closing where the script won't run. Are there any other more efficient methods for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the poller method is how i addressed this issue in the past. set flash to poll a php heartbeat script at a set interval which will up date the last access time of the users session. Then if the heartbeats stop the session clean up can clear out any expired sessions

Comment: How can we check if the heartbeat stops? won't the script stop executing once the user disconnects? Also can there be a script that checks continuously for such conditions as 'stoppage of heartbeat/polling' from multiple clients whose names are listed in the database and remove any idle clients? That script should run independently.

Comment: if the flash client is closed the heartbeats will stop. there should be some independent job that runs to expire sessions older than  a set amount of time

Comment: Well I didn't know how to run scripts that run independently. Using sleep() or other delay functions don't seem to work when user disconnects. Even connection_aborted() is not dependable. Using Zend amf complicates things. I achieved the polling technique by piggybacking some server maintenance/user-checking code here and there. So if any user invokes the script it'll do server clean up no matter what. Obviously there'll be some data left in the server- data of the last user. But that will be erased once a new user starts the script.T'was done by relying on the time() func.Hope its dependable.

Comment: you can create a cronjob that will be ran automatically by the server to do the cleanup